# How to automatically calculate the day for a given year?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

In input text field a year is entered (e.g. 2004). How to automatically calculate in which day of the week will Christmas fall that year by using JavaScript?

Comment: By Googling it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Comment: Please don't reference [w3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com). Reference ECMA-262, MDN or MSDN as appropriate.

Comment: @christopher http://w3fools.com Please don't link to w3schools.com!

Comment: @wumm - w3fools.com? Is it that outdated website that tells w3schools to wikify their content but they didn't do it on their own website? W3Schools has improved a lot of their materials over the last years, and even the creators/contributors of w3fools know it. They acknowledge that w3schools is actually not that bad and they even removed all the examples that "prove" w3schools is inaccurate in their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

halfnibble is pretty close, but unnecessarily uses parsing of a string rather than discrete values.

```
function getChristmasDayName(year) {
  var dayNames = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  var d = new Date(year, 11, 25);
  d.setFullYear(year); // required to support years 0 to 99
  return dayNames[d.getDay()];
}

alert(getChristmasDayName(2004)); // Saturday
```

The above assumes English day names and Gregorian calendar. Support for other languages will require additional arrays of day names in the language. Support for other calendars will require more work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var year = 2004,    //year
    dateObj = new Date(year, 11, 25);   //Note: 11 means "December"

dateObj.getDay();                                         //6
//Most reliable value.

dateObj.toString().substr(0, 3);                          //"Sat"
//Note: Although the specification does not specify the format of the returned
//      value of .toString, in most browsers, the first term should be the 
//      name of the day of the week. If you prefer a more "reliable" method,
//      use a custom Array with day names.

dateObj.toLocaleString("en", {weekday: "long"})       //"Saturday"
//Available in new browsers.
```

**About**

- `Date` constructor, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
- `Date.prototype.toString`, see [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2).
- `.toLocaleDateString`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

**Demo**

- http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dbnj2/ <sub><sup>(jQuery is only used for DOM manipulation)</sup></sub>

Comment: *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent, there is no reason to believe that it will, by default, put the day name first or conform to any particular format.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assign the year input to variable

```
var year = 2004 // Year entered into field input
```

Then you can do the following to get the day of week for a particular holiday:

```
// Use this array to create day of the week names:
var dayStringArray = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

// Create date of holiday with year entered.
var xmas = new Date(year, 11, 25); // 11 is for December (i.e. 12 - 1)
// This creates a Date object of Dec 25th, 2004

// Get day of week in 0 - 6 integer, then use array to get day text.
var xmasDayString = dayStringArray[xmas.getDay()];

console.log(xmasDayString); // Outputs "Saturday"
```